# I new to programming and study about operator overloading. To overload "+" to add two string

Tags: operator-overloading, strcpy, string.h

I new to programming and study about operator overloading. To overload "+" to add two string. But when I try to combine two string using strcpy, the second string replace the first string instead of copy with first string.

```
#include<string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

class String
{
    char str[100];
public:
    void operator +(String);
     String()
     {
         strcpy(str,"");
     }
     String(char a[100])
     {
         strcpy(str,a);

     }

};

void String::operator+ (String str1)
{ char temp[100];
  strcpy(temp,str);
  strcpy(temp,str1.str);
  cout<<temp;
}
int main()
{
    String s1=String("Hello");;
    String s2=String("World");
    s1+s2;


    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

The error in your code is that 
In the operator overloading function you should use strcat - string concatenation
For more info check out : [String concatenation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you've missed to assign the value of the two strings to a new string like this:

```
String nString = s1 + s2;
```